# MS-SQL Liquibase - Connection Could not be Created

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, liquibase

I am trying to setup liquibase for db deployment to MS SQL Server 2014. When I try to run an update (using command line), I get the following error message:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1234;databaseName=mydb" with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

My properties file is:

```
classpath=D:\\Tools\\Liquibase\\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\\sqljdbc_6.2\\enu\\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url="jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1234;databaseName=mydb"
username=MyUserName
password=SomePassword
changeLogFile=D:\\Tools\\Liquibase\\Test.sql
```

The liquibase batch file is being ran in the following environment:

```
Windows Server 2012
Java 1.8.0_31
```

I also tested the connection by using Microsoft's JDBC sample [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample). I added the mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar to my project and successfully ran a query using the same url, username, databaseName, and password from the properties file.

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1234;databaseName=mydb;user=MyUserName;password=SomePassword";
```

I am certain that I have the right driver and that a connection can be established. However, I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Debug Log:

```
    SEVERE 3/1/18 1:54 PM: liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:2431;databaseName=mydb;" with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  
Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:2431;databaseName=mydb;" with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. 

Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:127)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:958)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:188)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:2431;databaseName=mydb;" with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:247)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:151)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:85)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:2431;databaseName=mydb;" with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:242)
        ... 5 more
```

**RESOLVED:**

```
classpath=D:\\Tools\\Liquibase\\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\\sqljdbc_6.2\\enu\\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url=jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1234;databaseName=mydb
username=MyUserName
password=SomePassword
changeLogFile=D:\\Tools\\Liquibase\\Test.sql
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've added the stacktrace for you.

Comment: Are you sure that is the full stacktrace, and it doesn't have further causes?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  this is all the output i got from using --logLevel debug

Comment: Strange, I would have expected a SQLException. One other guess: your Java 8 version is pretty old, try with a newer version (Java 8 Update 162)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Unfortunately, I cannot update the JRE on the server. There are others using the server and updating the JRE may affect their applications.

The test application I made also ran a query fine in with the same JRE and JDBC. 

I guess i could try using an older version of liquibase?

Comment: I was more thinking along the line of an issue with the SQL Server JDBC driver and SSL a few years ago which was resolved by updating Java, but that might have been with a Java 7 version.

Answer (score 10):

I found the problem. The problem is the quotes (") around the url in the properties file. By removing the quotes, liquidbase ran fine..... a lot of brain hurt right now.

Comment: the removing quotes solution worked! Thanks a lot!